# Unstable webpage on zooming in or out

Tags: html, css

I am new to programming, and this is one of my first webpage. The HTML file has a header, 4 div containers and a footer.  When I zoom out all stay centered except the Header and first container(which sway to the extreme left. On zoom in everything gets squashed. How can i make it like normal webpages.

I tried changing the way i call the classes but no effect.

```
This is the html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div class="head">
                <div class="head1"><h3>Header Logo</h3></div> <div class="span"><span>header link one</span> <span>header link two</span> 
                <span>header link three</span></div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="container1">
                <div class="cont1div1">
                    <p class="p1">This Website is awesome</p><p>This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title. 
                    It's smaller font and the color is lower in contrast</p>
                    <button id="signup">Sign Up</button>
                </div>
                <div class="cont1div2">
                    <img src="fotos/jetback.jpg" alt="Jet about to take off" width="460" height="330">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container2">
                <div class="cont2div1">Some random information.</div>
                <div class="cont2div2">
                    <button id="btnpic1"><img src="fotos/fightjet1.jpg" alt="Fightjet1" width="200" height="200" /></button>
                    <button id="btnpic2"><img src="fotos/fightjet2.jpg" alt="Fightjet2" width="200" height="200" /></button>
                    <button id="btnpic3"><img src="fotos/fightjet3.jpg" alt="Fightjet3" width="200" height="200" /></button>
                    <button id="btnpic4"><img src="fotos/fightjet4.jpg" alt="Fightjet4" width="200" height="200" /></button>
                </div>
                <div class="cont2div3">
                    <h4>first link</h4>
                    <h4>second link</h4>
                    <h4>third link</h4>
                    <h4>fourth link</h4>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="container3">
                <div class="quote">This is an inspiring quote, or a testimonial from a customer. Maybe it's just filling up space, 
                or maybe people will actually read it. Who knows? All I know is that it looks nice.</div>
                <div class="sayer">-Thor, God of Thunder</div>
            </div>
            <div class="container4">
                <div class="cont4box">
                    <section>
                        <h2>Call to action! It's time!</h2>
                        <p>Sign up for our product by clicking that button right over there!</p>
                    </section>
                    <aside>
                        <button id="signup2">Sign Up</button>
                    </aside>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>Copyright © The Odin Project 2023</p>
            </footer>
    </body>
</html>

This is the CSS

body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #1F2937;
    color: #f9faf8;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

header {
    background-color: #1F2937;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.head {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.head1 h3 {
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.span {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 900px;
    gap: 2em;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.container1 {
    display: flex;
    margin: 100px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    gap: 15em;
}

.container1 .cont1div1 {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.container1 .cont1div2 {
    margin-left: 70px;
}

.container1 .p1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.container1 p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#signup {
    border: cadetblue;
    color: #f9faf8;
    background-color: #3882f6;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.container2 {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #1F2937;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.cont2div1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 1000;
    padding: 30px;
}

.cont2div2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    size: 90%;
    gap: 5em;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cont2div2 button {
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .1s ease;
    border: 6px solid grey;
}

.cont2div2 button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2)
}

.cont2div3 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    size: 90%;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 16em;
}

.container3 {
    color: #1F2937;
    background-color: #b5bbc3;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
    gap: 9em;
}

.quote {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 100px;
    width: 900px;
}

.sayer {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 550px;
}

.container4 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.container4 .cont4box {
    background-color: #3882f6;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.cont4box section {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.cont4box section h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
}

.cont4box section p {
    font-size: 19px;
    margin: 0;
}

.cont4box aside {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#signup2 {
    border: 3px solid #f9faf8;
    color: #f9faf8;
    background-color: #3882f6;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 140px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

footer {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;

}
```